# fgets() includes new line in string

Tags: c, fgets

I get the words from my document extracted and all are printed on screen, but after each word printed there is a blank line. How can I avoid reading or adding this new line to the string?

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *f;
    f = ("words", "r");
    char string[100];
    while (fgets(string, 100, f)) {
         printf("%s", string);
    }
}
```

This code was not copy pasted, so I could have forgotten tiny pieces but should work. In words.txt I have one word on each line. My program prints them all to screen, but adds a new line after each word. I do not want it to add a new line, or a space. So if the txt had `Hello` on one line and `Bye` on the next line, I want it to print `HelloBye`. The objective of the final program will not be to print the string, it will be to use the string for something else, so I do need a string that only has the text without spaces at the end or new lines.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *f;
    f = ("words", "r");
    char string[100];
    while (fgets(string, 100, f))
    {
        char * message = strtok(string, "\n");
        printf("%s", message);
    }
}
```

`strtok` tokenizes the string into `your message`, `\n`. `fgets` will capture the `\n` token

Comment: This work for my application. Getting correct results now. Thank you.

Comment: @liquidzorch no problem.

Comment: strtok is overkill here.

Comment: @SergeBallesta feel free to post your answer, then

Comment: Done. Anyway your solution is perfectly right and fully answers the question. Just thinking that looking if last character of a string is `\n` and replacing it with `\0` is somewhat simpler.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I'm happy for you

Comment: Be aware that while `strtok()` is OK in a main function like this, it is not usually OK in a library function because `strtok()` is — poisonous.  If a function that is using `strtok()` to parse a string calls another function that in turn uses `strtok()`, the calls in the other function wreck the behaviour of the sequence of calls in the calling function.  Similarly, the library function cannot call any function that in turn uses `strtok()` because its use of `strtok()` will be wrecked.  On Unix (POSIX) systems, use `strtok_r()`; on Windows, use `strtok_s()`.  These don't wreck things.

Answer (score 1):

*By design* `fgets` reads a line (terminated with a `\n`) and keeps the `\n` in the line - provided the buffer was big enough. Just look if last character is a `\n`, and it is it replace it with a `\0`, actually reducing the len of line by one:

```
int main(void)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = ("words", "r");
    char string[100];
    while (fgets(string, 100, f))
    {
         if ((string[0] != '\0') && (string[strlen(string) -1] == `\n')) {
             string[strlen(string) -1] = `\0';
         }
         printf("%s", string);
    }
}
```

Comment: The conditional code is complex compared with `string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';` — and inefficient if the compiler doesn't recognize that `strlen()` need only be called once as long as the result is saved.  The code using `strcspn()` works correctly even if the string is empty or contains no newline.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot *prevent* `fgets()` from storing the `'\n'` at the end of the array supplied to it. If the array is too short, `fgets()` will not store the newline, it will leave the characters that do not fit in the array in the input stream to be read by the next input operation.

There are multiple ways to remove the trailing newline, which may or may not be present:

Using `strcspn()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    FILE *f = fopen("words", "r");
    if (f != NULL) {
        while (fgets(string, sizeof string, f)) {
            string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = '\0';
            printf("%s", string);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `strlen()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    FILE *f = fopen("words", "r");
    if (f != NULL) {
        while (fgets(string, sizeof string, f)) {
            size_t len = strlen(string);
            if (len > 0 && string[len - 1] == '\n')
                string[--len] = '\0';
            printf("%s", string);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using `strchr()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[100];
    FILE *f = fopen("words", "r");
    if (f != NULL) {
        while (fgets(string, sizeof string, f)) {
            char *p = strchr(string, "\n");
            if (p != NULL)
                *p = '\0';
            printf("%s", string);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```